# Can't post to Twitter on iPhone using ShareKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Im using ShareKit for posting to Twitter and Facebook in my app. Facebook is working fine.

But when i tried to post on twitter firstly the message "saved" is showing and then immediately the alert message" Error unknown error" is showing and the message is not get posted in twitter.

Can anyone please help me with this.

I googled a lot and cant figure out the problem.

Hope for your help.Thanks in advance.

I used the below code:

```
[SHK setRootViewController:self];
UIImage *im = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newlog.jpg"];
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:im title:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Question: %@  \n  \n Answer: %@",t.text,t3]];
item.text=@"The  App";

SHKActionSheet *actionSheet1 =[SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];

[actionSheet1 showInView:self.view];
```

[image: Error image]

Comment: What iOS version are you targeting... 4? 5?

Comment: Are you checking the debug console? Logging all the network callbacks in the framework?

Comment: @Cirrostratus but facebook is working fine

Comment: What's your point? You should always use careful logging before moving on to any next steps.

Comment: im getting the same, it worked fine a week ago

Comment: any luck solving this problem?

Comment: The error seems to be "the server understood the request but is refusing to fulfill it"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log in into https://dev.twitter.com/ and go to My applications, select your app & go to settings tab:

[image]

set Application Type to Read and Write

[image]

now try to tweet using sharekit it may work. If you enable privacy settings in your twitter profile then also tweets won't get posted on your wall.

[image]

Remove the check mark (Protect my Tweets) & try to tweet again. If the issue is not with above mentioned cases then debug sharekit code.